# Build Docker nodejs image from scratch

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm pretty new to the whole docker thing,

I want to create a node-js image from scratch.
I searched the Internet a bit, but all I found is images are based on other node-js images.

I tried adding the node executables and editing the path accordingly, but still no luck. (Worked with java)

Sample dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/bin" 

ADD "node-v8.9.3-linux-x64.tar.xz" "rootfs.tar.xz"  /


ADD "prince.tar.gz" /

CMD ["node"]
```

Comment: You should add more details (source code) to your question

Comment: It is highly recommended to use official node-js docker image. Here is official image https://hub.docker.com/_/node/. Then you can add your stuff on top of this.

Comment: i need the image to be as lightweight as possible, the official images are too heavy.  and it would save me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand your goal is to build node-js image with minimum size, adding only node distribution might not work as underlying nodejs might need some other dependencies (if not available your OS).

You can quickly build image on top of alpine, the result image is around 60 MB only.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk add nodejs
```